# node js callback() function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Hello I am new to node js and I am trying to write a simple callback function however get "ReferenceError: sum1 is not defined", can anyone help me?
code:

```
sum1(1,2, function(sum){
  console.log(3 + sum);
});
sum1 = function (a,b, callback){
  callback(a + b);
};
```

However, I tried to use 
    `function sum1(a,b,callback){...}`
and it works. Is this a naming problem? Can anyone explain a little bit?

Comment: Function declarations are *hoisted*, function expressions are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to define the function before you call it.  When you use the form:

```
sum1 = function() {...}
```

to define your function, that definition MUST occur BEFORE you use the function.  That's because the function is not assigned to the `sum1` variable until that line of code executes.  So, if you try to execute `sum1(...)` before that line runs, then `sum1` is not yet defined and you get the exception.

If you use the form:

```
function sum1() {...}
```

Then, the symbol `sum1` is defined at parse time BEFORE any code executes so the order of placement in the file is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `sum1` prior to calling it, or use a function declaration:

```
// Define first:
var sum1 = function (a,b, callback){
    callback(a + b);
};
sum1(1, 2, function(sum) {
    console.log(3 + sum);
});
```

Or

```
// Function Declaration:
sum1(1, 2, function(sum) {
    console.log(3 + sum);
});
function sum1(a,b, callback){
    callback(a + b);
};
```

Function declarations can be after the code calling it.  However, for clarity's sake, you should always define a function (either way) before you use it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum1 = function (a,b, callback){
  callback(a + b);
};
```

This is a function expression , so you can't call `sum1()` before it's definition , move it above the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not in scope..
it's reference might need to be passed..
I had a similar issue in Protractor, so I had to pass the function reference and bingo it worked for me.. ;)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33364234)